# Given two arrays, how can I iterate over one and push to repeated elements of the second?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, unpivot

I'm writing a google apps script to take in a sheet with rows:

```
StudentName, StudentID, Gender, CoursePreference1, CoursePreference2, CoursePreference 3
```

and outputting:

```
StudentName, StudentID, Gender, CoursePreference1
StudentName, StudentID, Gender, CoursePreference2
StudentName, StudentID, Gender, CoursePreference3
```

I'm transforming the format so that instead of having one row per student with a column for each of their preferences, I'll have a row for each course preference with repeated student information.

I've tried to use other answers with nested for loops and the map method to get to where I'm going, but I'm completely tied in knots.

The first half of my code setting up two arrays works fine; each element of studentInfo is intended to be repeated for each element of the associated index of courseInfo:

```
function requestFileConversion() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName('Input');
  var output = ss.getSheetByName("Output");

  output.getRange('A2:I').clearContent();
  output.getRange('A2:I').setNumberFormat('@STRING@');

  var studentInfo = input.getRange(2, 1, input.getLastRow() - 1, 8).getValues();
  var courseInfo = input.getRange(2, 9, input.getLastRow() - 1, 23).getValues();

  var appendValues = [];
```

then the second half is where I've broken down; my completely non-functional attempt looks like this:

```
 for (var i=0; i < courseInfo.length; i++) {
    var requestCollection = [];
    for (var j=0; j < courseInfo[i].length; j++) {
      requestCollection.push(studentInfo[i] + courseInfo[j]);
    };

if (requestCollection.length > 0) {
Array.prototype.push.apply(appendValues, requestCollection);
};
};
```

The desired results of the transformation is to go from a set of rows in the form:

```
Jenny, id100, F, English, Science, Math, Physics
Johnny, id101, M, Science, Sports, Gym, English
```

and produce:

```
Jenny, id100, F, English
Jenny, id100, F, Science
Jenny, id100, F, Math
Jenny, id100, F, Physics
Johnny, id101, M, Science
Johnny, id101, M, Sports
Johnny, id101, M, Gym
Johnny, id101, M, English
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about the relationship between ``studentInfo``, ``courseInfo`` and the values of  ``Jenny, id100, F, English, Science, Math, Physics``. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) operations and then map to recombine.

```js
data = [
  ['Jenny', 'id100', 'F', 'English', 'Science', 'Math', 'Physics'],
  ['Johnny', 'id101', 'M', 'Science', 'Sports', 'Gym', 'English']
];

result = [];
data.map(row => {
  var [name, id, gender, ...prefs] = row;
  prefs.map((x) => result.push([name, id, gender, x]));
})
console.log(result);
```

As pointed out in the comments, since some of the features [might not be available](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features), here's a more conservative alternative.

```js
data.forEach(function(row) {
  prefs = row.slice(3);  
  prefs.map(function(x) { result.push([row[0], row[1], row[2], x]) });
})
```

Comment: I don't think Google Apps Script support arrow operators in map.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I used the more conservative approach in Gsheets, but I learned a lot but working through the first version because I haven't any experience with arrow operators. This worked perfectly and I was able to adapt it to exactly what I need! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addingRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    vt=vA[i].slice(3);
    for(var j=0;j<vt.length;j++) {
      vB.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][1],vA[i][2],vt[j]])
    }
  }
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  osh.appendRow(['Name','ID','Gender','Course']);
  osh.getRange(2,1,vB.length,4).setValues(vB);
}
```

My Sheet1:

[image]

My Sheet2:

[image]

- [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)